# Is it possible to navigate page in windows 8 application using navigation uri of hyperlinkbutton xaml page?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

In Windows phone if 
`this.HyperLinkButton.NavigateUri = new Uri("PageName", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);`
is used it navigates to the respective page

But in **WinRT /Windows8** this crashes the app.

I cannot use `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageName)` as I am creating a dll and I cannot find the page, the only attribute I have is navigation uri ( i.e **pageName.xaml**) existing in the project in which this dll will be included.

Comment: Are you creating a dll at runtime?

Comment: Can you show more code?  I wrote something up quickly, and i'm able to use the HyperLinkButton successfully...

Comment: How are you planinng to load / distribute the dll? Aren't you going to reference it in your main project?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(Type.GetType("MyNameSpace.PageName", "MyAssembly");
```

The page name is without the '.xaml'.

Greets